# Code is executing in both the IF and ELSE statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I have run into some errors in which my function seems to be reading in both if and else statements that I have created, instead of either one at a time.

So what I am trying to do is that, if it reads the importing file, first line/first character, if it is not [B]v[/B], it will prompts a warning and asked the user to re-import the relevant file. Else, if the file is correct, it will go on and creates the locators and group it.
Example - The file line in the correct obj file should be: [I]v -0.6110637188 0.0093309134 8.1327419281[/I]

As soon as I tried another obj file in which it first line is started off as [I]# This is a testing file...[/I] I was prompted with tons of errors as follows:

```
# Warning: Please import in a relevant Point Cloud Obj # 
# Warning: Please import in a relevant Point Cloud Obj # 
# Warning: Please import in a relevant Point Cloud Obj # 
# Warning: Please import in a relevant Point Cloud Obj # 
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
This part works if importing the right point cloud
# Failed to read file information
# Error: list index out of range
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 62, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 16, in __init__
#   File "<maya console>", line 58, in processLine
# IndexError: list index out of range #
```

As you can see in the error log, it is printing the statement that I have inputted in both if and else statements. Apparently, despite the first letter is wrong, it just keeps on iterating to the next line.. Additionally, it is creating out the locators as well which it should not be. This is my code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sys, os
import string

class ObjCloud():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            fileHandle = open("/user_data/aaa.obj","r")
            filePath = os.path.basename(fileHandle.name)
            fileName = os.path.splitext(filePath)[0]

            for line in fileHandle:
                self.processLine(line)
            fileHandle.close()
        except:
            sys.stderr.write( "Failed to read file information\n")
            raise

        cmds.select("locator*")
        objGroup = cmds.group(n=("pointCloud_" + fileName))
        cmds.xform(os=True, piv=(0, 0, 0))
        cmds.scale(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
        cmds.delete(constructionHistory=True)

        cmds.select(objGroup)
        cmds.group(n="cameraTrack")
        cmds.scale(10, 10, 10)

    def processLine(self, line):
        if(line[0] != "v"):
            cmds.warning("Please import in a relevant Point Cloud Obj")
        else:
            brokenString = string.split(line)

            cmds.spaceLocator(absolute=True, position=(\
            float(brokenString[1])*100\
            , float(brokenString[2])*100\
            , float(brokenString[3])*100))
```

EDIT: The obj file contains a list of data (positional values), and by using the values it will creates out the locator prior to that

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently, despite the first letter is wrong, it just keeps on
>   iterating to the next line..

what in your code would prevent that? You need to add a check to break this loop:

```
for line in fileHandle:
    self.processLine(line)
```

in case the function returns a wrong value, or alternatively throw an exception in addition to the warning.

Comment: I would say in this case, my check would be the `if-else` in the processLine function but apparently it is not working

Comment: your code executes the `if`, returns and moves on to the next line. Your comment suggests you want it to stop iterating over the lines. IF that is what youre looking for, you can add `raise Exception("bad path")` after printing the warning, and this will obviously stop the loop.

Comment: Wow.. The code you have provided works like magic?! Then again, correct me if I am wrong as I have hardly played with this sort of `raise` etc, am I suppose to see the `raise` that I have defined back in the `except` statement as well as some `Traceback` errors too?

Comment: the `bad path` exception will be caught by your `except`, which in turn will raise another exception, after writing to the `stderr`. you will get the stack trace for that unhanded exception eventually.

Comment: So is this a good or bad thing? Will it cause any difficulties should someone else going to use my file for editing purposes?

Comment: good or bad? hard to tell... depends on the broader context I guess. But having said that, using `except` without specifying what kind of exception it catches is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

there few things you need to do

1. First you need find the line is empty or not using `line.strip()==''` since if it empty one cannot index it so your getting index out of range error or you can use if `line.startswith('v')`
2. if you want to search one file whose first character then why are you reading total lines

here your sending each line of the file to the processLine

```
for line in fileHandle:
        self.processLine(line)
```

try

```
self.processLine(fileHandle.readlines()[0])
```

Comment: The reason I send each line to process line is because the obj file contains a list of positional values, and so, locators will be created based on those values. I have tried out your method 1, and I am getting the same values. As for the method 2, it is as what I have mentioned. I thought by defining it using the `if-else` it will help me to 'break' and stop the execution

Comment: Just like to add, `self.processLine(fileHandle.readlines()[0])` this has helps to rectify if the first character is not `v` but.. If I open the correct obj file, this time round, it prompts `# Failed to read file information
# Error: list index out of range`

Comment: @dissidia so if the first line is not the searching word. do you need to stop total excution of file. is it right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That would means the user either has to re-input the correct file directory or close the application

Comment: Exceptions can seem a bit hard to understand if you haven't used them before. The [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) has a good introduction with some simple examples, but there are also lots of good articles and tutorials on the Net.